# JWT Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My team is building a web api in .net core. We use token authentication to authenticate any client, the token comes form the Azure AD.

We put this code in Startup.cs

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;               
            options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/1da3434a9-e5a6-4e9e-80c3-aca8ed37cb03";               
            options.Audience = "https://test.onmicrosoft.com/test_api";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // Define one or more CORS policies
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
```

This one only work when we allow anonymous access. I checked the token, and the token is valid. But every time we hit controller it will throw cors error. even though we enable cors

Comment: Could you show us the CORS code?

Comment: @Danny, I updated my post and add the CORS code

Comment: Thanks. Could you show the exact error message?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44395/api/siteget/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44378' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of adding middleware does matter!

> To enable CORS for your entire application add the CORS middleware to
>   your request pipeline using the `UseCors` extension method. Note that
>   the CORS middleware must proceed any defined endpoints in your app
>   that you want to support cross-origin requests (ex. before any call to
>   `UseMvc`).

You should put `services.AddCors` above almost everything that might redirect your users via 401.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine AllowCredentials & AllowAnyOrigin. Pick a specific origin and your request will likely work.